# Remove adjoining column whitespace in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, whitespace

I'll just post a picture to make this all easier to understand, as posting a JSfiddle would involve a huge amount of html and loads of formatting CSS (responsive picture triangles).

I have two rows in bootstrap, one row has 3 divs, each "col-sm-4". The second row has 4 divs, each "col-sm-3". There are large whitespace gaps where the columns adjoin, because the images are triangles. Is there anyway to maybe overlap the columns (or do something else entirely) to remove that whitespace and make all the triangles closer, and the same size?

[image: Screenshot of webpage in desktop view]

Answer (score 1):

col-sm-4 takes a width of 33.33% on the device viewport try decreasing the width of .col-sm-4 in your style sheet by giving it higher specificity meaning .col-sm-4 takes 33.33% in bootstrapmin.css in your stylesheet gives your outer div class name as triangle-container and in your stylesheet declare .traingle-container .col-sm-4 and give them a width of 15%. In that way it comes closer together.

Answer (score 0):

the class dontwantpadding will do the trick for you. In your div you will just have to add the class so something like `<div class="col-sm-4 dontwantpadding"></div>`

in the custom css you will have a class:

```
.dontwantpadding {
    margin: 0 !important;
   padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: This helps to an extent, but only removes the padding. The columns themselves are still preventing the triangles from getting closer

Comment: how is your image like? it is probably coming from the images since they are have some space between them right? so you can photoshop them and reshape them.

Comment: Yes, the images themselves are rectangular, and are adjoining when the margin and padding is removed. However, I'm hoping to to a hover-to-show for the full image, so photoshopping the actual images into triangles doesn't really work. Is there a way to temporarily overlap columns?